# What are good Z+T strategies for multiplayer Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran

In a 2v2 game, if two Zergs are in one team they often do a "double-6-pool-rush". Even though almost everybody knows this opening, it is still very difficult to counter it, although possible.

Does there exist a similarly good opening for a Terran and Zerg team?

Comment: You can turn your question into a [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) by flagging it for moderator attention and asking it there.

Comment: IMO, this doesn't need to be Community Wiki; but if you confirm that's what you want I'll turn it.

Comment: Juan, guess, you better know what it is. But from my perspective it will be interest to everybody, not to me only...

Comment: A Community Wiki indicates that the community is creating this question.  I don't see any need to collaborate on the question.  If people feel to collaborate on a specific answer, we can always mark those as CW separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a basic rush opener for Z+T, you can go 6-Pool and Mega-Rax. Mega-Rax is the same sort of thing as 6-pool, just build lots of barracks and marines. Skip gas collection, but do get an Orbital Command for MULEs. Build 3 early barracks and more as you can afford them. One advantage of the Z+T composition is that Zerglings can form a front, tanking damage, while the marines can stand behind them and dish out damage. You can Google "Mega Rax" for more ideas or an exact build order.

However, I'd encourage you to broaden your horizons. These "builds" are all-in rushes. If they do not work, for example if your opponents have defended walls, you are left with a slow economy (especially for the Zerg), no tech advantages, and only the capability to build the most basic units. Opponents going for Roaches, Marauders, Tanks, Stalkers etc will steamroll you if your initial wave doesn't win the game.

So, of course feel free to play with rushes if you enjoy them, but you may also consider looking at other nice strategies and synergies, such as Medivacs healing Zerg units, or maybe Muta harassment + tank pushing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [this cast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj3tP5Jk4SU) demonstrates exactly the case you are talking about and a good strategy against it.

Comment: GOOD cast, very good +1 for it. But, it is not about my question. I asked about T+Z opening...

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place to start looking:

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/TZ_Strategy

Comment: If you feel the need to link to another site can you at least summarize the content?  It helps for when links become stale.